# How do I get an even spread between my bubbles?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bubble chart in D3. I have it working for displaying about 1,000 bubbles, but I'd like to make it work to display 2 or even 3 thousand bubbles. I'm taking inspiration from [Shirley Wu](http://sxywu.com/)'s amazing visualization with Guardian [here](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/ng-interactive/2017/dec/20/bussed-out-america-moves-homeless-people-country-study).

My bubbles have an uneven spread where more of them are packed in towards the center.

[image]

I'd like to get it so they are evenly spread out across the whole space, like this.

[image]

These are the components that I've been trying to manipulate.

```
// Forces
const radius = 1.5
const padding1 = 15;
const padding2 = 5;
const strength = .3
const alpha = .1
const alpha_decay = 0
const alpha_min = 0.001
const alpha_Collision = .03;
const charge_strength = -.5
const charge_theta = .9
const veloc_decay = .5
```

And this is the code where my force is defined.

```
  // Circle for each node.
    const circle = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes)
        .join("circle")
          .attr("cx", d => d.x)
          .attr("cy", d => d.y)
          .attr("fill", d => d.color)
          .attr("r", d => d.r);

     // Forces
     const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
         .force("x", d => d3.forceX(d.x))
         .force("y", d => d3.forceY(d.y))
         .force("cluster", forceCluster())
         .force("collide", forceCollide())
         .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(charge_strength).theta(charge_theta))
         .alpha(alpha)
         .alphaDecay(alpha_decay)
         .alphaMin(alpha_min)
         .velocityDecay(veloc_decay);

     // Adjust position of circles.
      simulation.on("tick", () => {
          circle
              .attr("cx", d => d.x)
              .attr("cy", d => d.y)
              .attr("fill", d => groups[d.group].color);
          });

      // Force to increment nodes to groups.
      function forceCluster() {
        let nodes;

        function force(alpha) {
          const l = alpha * strength;
          for (const d of nodes) {
            d.vx -= (d.x - groups[d.group].x) * l;
            d.vy -= (d.y - groups[d.group].y) * l;
          }
        }
        force.initialize = _ => nodes = _;

        return force;
      }

      // Force for collision detection.
      function forceCollide() {
        let nodes;
        let maxRadius;

        function force() {
          const quadtree = d3.quadtree(nodes, d => d.x, d => d.y);
          for (const d of nodes) {
            const r = d.r + maxRadius;
            const nx1 = d.x - r, ny1 = d.y - r;
            const nx2 = d.x + r, ny2 = d.y + r;
            quadtree.visit((q, x1, y1, x2, y2) => {

              if (!q.length) do {
                if (q.data !== d) {
                  const r = d.r + q.data.r + (d.group === q.data.group ? padding1 : padding2);
                  let x = d.x - q.data.x, y = d.y - q.data.y, l = Math.hypot(x, y);
                  if (l < r) {
                    l = (l - r) / l * alpha_Collision;
                    d.x -= x *= l, d.y -= y *= l;
                    q.data.x += x, q.data.y += y;
                  }
                }
              } while (q = q.next);
              return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
            });
          }
        }

        force.initialize = _ => maxRadius = d3.max(nodes = _, d => d.r) + Math.max(padding1, padding2);

        return force;
      }
```

I have the code uploaded [here](https://bl.ocks.org/wdtglrn/011393246f477c520bd39095c2eeafe4/e236adb31232e85dc9ceeadc470c390e552547a4). Part of the problem is that the bubbles in the center are constantly moving. It's like they're trying to find a spot to settle in, but the width of the space is not large enough (except that if I make it bigger, the whole blob becomes too large).

I don't know how to stop the movement. It looks nicer when I set `alpha_decay` to `.1` but the bubbles change location on the visualization from `unaware` to `aware` and they won't move if `alpha_decay > 0`.

How can I get the bubbles evenly spread out without clustering in the center, like shown in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use native d3 force methods to achieve it. Just play with the different forces of charge, center and collision.

```js
height = 300;
width = 300;

const nodes = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ];
  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(0.4))
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(6))
    .on('tick', ticked);

  function ticked() {
    var u = d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes)

    u.enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', 5)
      .merge(u)
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return d.x
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d.y
      });

    u.exit().remove()
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: If you get a chance, can you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998037/how-do-i-set-boundaries-for-my-bubbles-and-trigger-movement-on-command