# How can I keep my bubbles still unless there is a state change?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I posted a previous question similar to this, but that post has two separate issues and so I think it'll get taken down. I'm putting this here, but let me know if it'd be better for me to edit [the old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998037/how-do-i-set-boundaries-for-my-bubbles-and-trigger-movement-on-command).

I have a bubble chart. I'd like to get the bubbles to stay in one place, unless they need to change states, as represented by moving down the SVG. You can see the full visualization [here](https://bl.ocks.org/wdtglrn/fb8c1f1624e2ca2aca6fd5fb585beb3a/8f3caac27dd88900c0472f55ded753eb20028fd8).

Right now, I have the bubbles set up so that they start with `.alpha(.03)` and `alphaDecay(0)`. It's a nice solution since it keeps them energized, so they can move states. But, it means the bubbles never stop moving and I can't send alphaDecay higher than 0.

Is it possible to get the bubbles to stay still, except when they need to move across the screen?